# Round Up Integer Number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, rounding

I want to round up my integer number in javascript, here the case.

i have a code for calculating

```
document.getElementById("finalNumber").value = (((varNum1 * 0.09) * varNum2 / 12)/varNum3);
```

the finalNumber return  = **918740**

how can i change the return into **918800** so the 740 into 800, for another example if the finalNumber return 918800 it should be not change.

Comment: Are you sure, you want to round 740 to 800? Because ideally it should be 700.